# Python3:tkinter:Botão executa sozinho

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button

boa tarde
Eu estava a estudar interfaces gráficas em tkinter e surgiu este problema
A minha interface possui um botão simples e a função dele era simplesmente imprimir o conteudo de uma variavel que era passada em argumento, porem este quando e criado ele executa automaticamente e depois quando carrego nele ele não executa mais
Segue o código:

```
from tkinter import *
class teste():
        def batata(self,T):
                print(T)
        def __init__(self):
                root = Tk()
                root.title("Teste")
                root.geometry("800x600")
                nome='Avocado'
                Frame1 = Frame(root)
                self.listagem=["livro","pedra"]
                Frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 0,rowspan=2,sticky = W+E+N+S)
                Texto1=Label(Frame1,text=self.listagem[0]).grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=2,pady=10)
                ButtCarderno1=Button(Frame1,text=self.listagem[0],command=self.batata(self.listagem[0])).grid(row=2,column=0,rowspan=2,pady=1)
                root.mainloop()


teste()
```

se alguem souber o que se passa agradeço pk por mais que procure não encontro respostas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo, pois você acaba invocando o método `batata` quando cria o botão:

```
ButtCarderno1=Button(Frame1,text=self.listagem[0],command=self.batata(self.listagem[0])).grid(row=2,column=0,rowspan=2,pady=1)
```

Com isso o `command` do seu botão acaba na verdade ficando com o retorno do método `batata`, ou seja, nulo, perceba que se você clicar nesse botão após a janela ser aberta, não acontecerá nada.

---

Veja esse exemplo simplificado de uma função no botão:

```
def batata():
    print("livro")

root = Tk()
root.title("Teste")
root.geometry("800x600")
frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0,rowspan=2,sticky = W+E+N+S)
texto = Label(frame,text="livro").grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=2,pady=10)
botao = Button(frame,text="livro",command=batata).grid(row=2,column=0,rowspan=2,pady=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Perceba que eu atribui a função `batata` no `command`, mas não invoquei a mesma, com isso a tela é criada sem chamar a função `batata` e ao clicar no botão é exibido *livro* no console.

---

Como você deseja enviar parâmetros para o `command` do botão, você pode utilizar de uma `lambda`, com isso a função não é executada de imediato, somente quando o botão é clicado:

```
ButtCarderno1=Button(Frame1,text=self.listagem[0],command=lambda: self.batata(self.listagem[0])).grid(row=2,column=0,rowspan=2,pady=1)
```

Perceba que agora o `command` receba uma `lambda` *(command=lambda)*, que por sua vez vai invocar o método batata.

---

Seu código então ficará mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
from tkinter import *

class teste():

    def batata(self,T):
        print(T)

    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.title("Teste")
        root.geometry("800x600")
        nome='Avocado'
        Frame1 = Frame(root)
        self.listagem=["livro","pedra"]
        Frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 0,rowspan=2,sticky = W+E+N+S)
        Texto1=Label(Frame1,text=self.listagem[0]).grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=2,pady=10)
        ButtCarderno1=Button(Frame1,text=self.listagem[0],command=lambda: self.batata(self.listagem[0])).grid(row=2,column=0,rowspan=2,pady=1)
        root.mainloop()


teste()
```